# How to use order and where in Socrata SOQL in a big table NYC 311 table?

Tags: socrata

I apologize if this is obvious but please see:

```
curl 'https://data.cityofnewyork.us/resource/fhrw-4uyv.json?$order=created_date+desc'
```

if you focus on `created_date`

returns:

```
      "created_date" : "2016-04-30T02:55:27.000"
      "created_date" : "2016-04-30T02:34:58.000",
      "created_date" : "2016-04-30T02:13:14.000",
```

NOTICE **2016-04-30T02:55:27.000** is close to the current date and time

But

```
curl 'https://data.cityofnewyork.us/resource/fhrw-4uyv.json?incident_zip=%2711205%27&$order=created_date+desc&$limit=1'
```

returns:

```
"created_date": "2015-04-16T23:25:08.000",
```

NOTICE **2015-04-16T23:25:08.000** is about a YEAR AGO!  But it should be 2016.  What is incorrect?

Even a simple request such as:

```
curl 'https://data.cityofnewyork.us/resource/fhrw-4uyv.json?$select=created_date&$order=created_date+desc'
```

returns

```
,{"created_date":"2015-04-17T02:10:54.000"}
,{"created_date":"2015-04-17T02:07:08.000"}
,{"created_date":"2015-04-17T02:06:11.000"}
,{"created_date":"2015-04-17T02:05:33.000"}
```

Please use the NYC 311 table.  It may be related to the size of the table.  Thanks.

Comment: Ralph - It looks like an update is under way on that dataset, and something fishy is going on. I'm chatting with our engineers about it, and I'll update you after we figure out what is going on

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Our engineers were able to resolve the issue and things should be returning results that are more sane now. Let me know if things look good from your end too.

Comment: Yes it looks good now. Thanks! If you could please explain what happened.

Comment: I'll have to dig in with them on the ultimate root cause, but it looks like it was a caching bug that caused the query index cache to return the wrong results.